# React, Jest, spyOn export module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

setupTests.ts:

```
 jest.mock('hooks', () => ({
  useCurrentUser: () => mockOwner,
}));
```

component.test.ts:

```
import * as hooks from 'hooks';
test('delete organization', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(hooks, 'useCurrentUser').mockReturnValueOnce({
      ...mockOwner,
      tenantId: 2,
    });

    render(
      <MockedProvider>
        <GeneralSettings organization={{ ...mockOrganization }} />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(await screen.findByTestId('delete-org')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

hook.ts

`export * from './use-current-user.hook';`

my spyOn function doesn't work because I import specific functions from the file in my components
`import { useCurrentUser } from 'hooks';`.

It works only if I use `import * as hooks from 'hooks';` in my components

how can I spyOn my  `useCurrentUser` ?

I tried to find a solution on the Internet, but nowhere does it say how to override this case

Comment: If useCurrentUser is already mocked in the Setup. mockOwner.mockReturnValue() can be added.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `useCurrentUser` does, but the normal way you'd do this is to just wrap your component in the context that `useCurrentUser` is probably hooked into. *Editorial note: this is one of the many reasons I think hooks are shit.*

I usually architect things so that *most* of my logic uses dependency injection, and then if I feel like there's still significant functionality that needs tests, I'll do that at the very top layer and test that separately.

So I might have an `EditUser` component that takes user and `setUser` as props. Then, I'd just check that as the user interacts with `EditUser` that everything looks like it should for the editing process and that `setUser` receives a user in the correct state after editing. For this amount of functionality, I probably wouldn't test the integration of the parent component, `EditUser`, and `useCurrentUser`. But I might have tests for `useCurrentUser` and any utilities the parent might use to create a user in the correct state to go into `EditUser` if there's not an existing user.